# Trying to create a global file mapping object from a user-mode process fails

Tags: windows, winapi, shared-memory, file-mapping

I have a Windows app that runs without requiring elevation. I need to create a file mapping object for a memory array to be shared between all running instances of the app (note that some of those instances may run in different logon sessions.)

I call the [CreateFileMapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API to create it, with a global name, i.e. `Global\sharedname`, using a security descriptor that gives `all` access to `everyone` but that API fails with error code 5, or `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`.

I then started reading the docs and found that my process is required the `SeCreateGlobalPrivilege` privilege. But then when I try to assign that privilege the [AdjustTokenPrivileges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375202%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) returns error code `ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED`, and I'm stuck....

So what's the trick here, how does that freakin' MS want us to do it???

PS. I can previously create a global named mutex (for synchronized access to the shared memory) with the same `all access for everyone` security descriptor and `Global\sharedmutex` name without a problem.

Comment: From what I can tell, "GLOBAL\sharedname" is for creating objects that can be accessed from all sessions.  Do you really need this to be accessed from multiple sessions or just by multiple processes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only administrators, and services running in session 0, can gain the `SeCreateGlobalPrivilege` privilege needed to create file mappings in the `Global` namespace.  Assuming you do not want to re-write your code into a service, you will have to spawn a separate elevated process to create the file mapping.

Comment: Thanks for your confirmation. I was inclining to think so. On the side note, how ridiculous to impose this limitation? Why can't we share data among non-elevated processes... Anyway, it's not a question, it's just my frustration with the platform. And to answer your point, no, I can't spawn an elevated process. The workaround is to use shared file system file to share data. The only downside is that it will be pretty insecure, since I will have to change its ACL to `everyone has read-write access`.